# output an internal array of strings and how many times they occur in a file

Tags: arrays, bash, unix

I need to create an array in a script and output each string in the array along with the number of times it occurs in a text file. The output should look like this:

```
wheel  20               
the    10           
want   3           
from   6
```

This is what I have so far however I am getting multiple syntactical errors. I am very new to unix.

```
declare -a arr=("wheel" "The" "want" "from")
for i in "$(arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i" | tr -s ' ' '\n' < audi_dudi.txt | grep -c '$i'
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there, just that the piping is a bit broken, and there are a couple of typos.

You already have a good idea of what has to be done, so instead of pointing you to a new way of doing this, I will just point you to how to fix what you have. The following is what you were doing, with minimal changes described after the code:

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   tr -s ' ' '\n' < audi_dudi.txt | grep -c "$i"
done
```

Note the changes:

1. You have a `(` instead of a `{` while iterating over array.
2. You don't have to pipe the match argument `i`, that breaks everything.
3. Variables are not expanded in single quotes, so fix that (this is a *nix newbie classic btw).